# How to add a "lantern-like" effect using p5.js 2D?

Tags: p5.js

I'm trying to add a light effect, like a lantern, on a simple game using p5.js.
So, I have a background image and a player who is the source of the light (so it will go a radius from him).

I used a circle with RGBA color to make this effect, so it lights the background close to the player, but the problem is that the rest of the background is still visible, when it should be all dark, and I couldn't find a method in p5.js to handle that.

As an example of what I want to achieve, there's [this game on itch.io](https://sweaters.itch.io/lantern) that does exactly that.

Comment: Can you share your code so far? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to give the circle pixels of the "background" image
As i cannot comment right now, I suggest you color few background pixels by some shape,
You would not find, i think so to open a hole to the front dark image.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Although this tool

```
pixC = color(yourBImagePlace.get(x, y));
```

will not give your perfect result

```
Class fireParticle{ ...
  show() {
    noStroke();
    fill(this.pixC);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.radius);
  }

  move() {
    this.x += random(-5, 5);
    this.y -= random(1, 3);
  }
}
```

you can always try some
kernels
|| convolution
(computer vision techniques)